# python-constraints solutions with entire range of days

Tags: python, constraints

So i need to have numerous variables.
One named days. Each solution need to contain the entire range from 1 to 294.
For each day I then have numerous variables, A, B, C, D which can contain values from 1 to 7.

How to define this?

How to define that A needs to be the same (eg. 1) on 7 days before it needs to change.

Ok, this is what i got so far.
This accept a solution for only 1 day, not range of 294 days.

```
from constraint import *

problem = Problem()
problem.addVariable("days", range(1,294))
problem.addVariable("f", [1,2,3,4,5,6,7])
problem.addVariable("e", [1,2,3,4,5,6,7])
problem.addVariable("n", [1,2,3,4,5,6,7])
problem.addVariable("o", [1,2,3,4,5,6,7])

problem.addConstraint(AllDifferentConstraint())
#problem.addConstraint(SomeInSetConstraint([1], exact=42))
print(problem.getSolution())
```

Comment: what have you tried so far? and post your expected output.

Comment: added what i got so far, expected outputs would be 294 days of different variables of f e n o, where non of them are alike. i then need to add constraints on top of that, but so far I only get one day. The solution should follow days, like 1 -> 2 -> 294.